# How can I add Laravel Authentication to an initiated Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-6, laravel-artisan, laravel-ui

is it safe to add Laravel Auth into a project that already started? I'm sure we are not using any Authentication alternative.

Comment: hmm. so your app doesn't have any authentication at the moment? even the one Laravel itself provides out of the box?

Comment: I want to use the Laravel's Auth solution itself, but reading the documentation, they recommend to do it in a new project.

Comment: I don't think they recommend doing it in a new project. The documentation is just set up to show how to do it in a new project. You can do it in any project assuming you don't already have any conflicting resources. Use source control just to be safe

Comment: its pretty easy to do, if you havent already. And it integrates pretty well. Read the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait and you should know how to integrate in your project

Comment: I recommend you use OAuth 2.0. It is often used in laravel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to provide a small overview of the project, I'm using:
- Laravel 6.x
- I already Import Laravel UI to use Vue.js in some components

In case you already started your project, you just need to be aware of the following:

1. Your project doesn't modify any of the following files:

   - app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php
   - app/Http/Controllers/Auth/*
   - resources/js/app
   - resources/views/layouts
2. You are not using a FrontEnd Library with Laravel UI. This is important because depending on the command you use to start the scaffolding, you can override the app.js file on /resources/js.
3. You are not overwriting any of the routes of the Auth created by `Auth::routes()`.

To add the Authentication first include laravel/ui with composer:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Once you've installed laravel/ui you can see the new artisan's commands:

```
php artisan ui --help
```

To include the auth scaffolding, I recommend to use the following command:

```
php artisan ui:auth
```

I prefer this command because it's safer and it's confirm before overwriting any existing file.